# Is it possible to distribute Selenium tests on several machines where several browsers are used in tests from TFS 2018?

Tags: selenium, tfs

This question is related to TFS 2018. We'd like to add this to the release pipeline for a release.

The title isn't a truly accurate representation of the problem.

Here's what we would like to accomplish:

1. Run a set of Selenium tests that come from a test assembly
2. Those tests should run on several browsers.
3. But those tests should also be distributed to several machines so that different tests run on each machine per browser.

The tests should run on each browser, and the tests themselves should be distributed and be run on different agents.

So for example, on the first run, we use Firefox, and test #1 goes to agent 1, test #2 goes to agent 2 and test #3 goes to agent 3. And then on the second run, Chrome is used and the same test distribution as before is used.

[Here's a visual representation of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXN25.png)

Comment: yes, It's possible.
You can check Selenium Grid for this.

Comment: Ah sorry, should've specified that the question is related to TFS 2018 in the title and question body. Is it still possible to use Selenium Grid with TFS?

Comment: Yes, you can distribute the test on different machine with different browsers using selenium grid. kindly go through the selenium grid documentation.

Comment: Try this simple example https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html

Comment: @sb_w It's able to use parallel environments and release promotion in test automation. Details please refer this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/23/using-parallel-environments-and-release-promotion-in-test-automation/).